# MS Access Date Comparison and update another Field

Tags: ms-access

I have data entry form with TWO date field and one IMPortance Field. CreationDate and Target Date. If I have IMPortance field is yes , I want to compare date fields and if Date difference  are  <1 week want to update RISK field as  EMERGENCY, 1 week to 52 week its HIGH , >12 Month to 24M Its Medium else LOW.
I tried with DateDiff but could not achieve above. please help

I tried using after change IMPortance field
DateDiff( "w", CretionDate,TargetDate) <52 and >1
Me.RISK = "HIGH"

Need help please

Answer (score 1):

You can use this expression as ControlSource for your RISK textbox on the form:

```
=IIf(DateDiff("d", [CreationDate], [TargetDate]) < 7, "EMERGENCY", IIf(DateDiff("ww", [CreationDate], [TargetDate]) < 52, "HIGH", IIf(DateDiff("m", [CreationDate], [TargetDate]) < 24, "MEDIUM", "LOW")))
```

If comma is not your *list separator*, replace with semicolon.